# How to control the frequency range of Spectrogram?

Tags: plotting

How do you control the frequency range of Spectrogram? There is no obvious option. The documentation says it uses the same options as ArrayPlot, but PlotRange does not work in the way expected (it is probably controlling the contrast of the rendered image).

Here is an example. I would like the frequency range to extend only up to 4000. The default maximum frequency appears to be the Nyquist (samplerate/2) which is sensible, but not what I want.

```
samplerate = 16000;
seconds = 1;
samples = Round[seconds samplerate];
ratios = 2 Pi  {1., 1700/500., 2500/500.}/samplerate;
hz = 500;
waves = Transpose[
   Chop[ Table[Sin[hz ratios t ], {t, 0, samples - 1}]]];
list = Total[waves];
Spectrogram[list, SampleRate -> samplerate]
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Other than using sample rate which determines time/frequency, there is no specific option. Do you mean, for example, you have some spectrogram but you'd like to "zoom in" on some range?

Comment: Yes. These are speech sounds so the meaningful range extends to 4000 Hz, but for other reasons I would like to use a samplerate of 16000 Hz.

Comment: from help, it says you can specify sample rate.  `Spectrogram displays only the first half of the magnitude of the discrete Fourier transform due to the symmetry property of the transform` if you give sample rate `r` then the frequency range is : `For the setting SampleRate->r and a list of length m, time is ranged from 0 to m/r, and the frequencies are in the range 0 to r/2.`

Comment: @Nasser I am aware of those defaults, but I am trying to escape from them.